# Android - problems with JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I have the following code (stored as .c file) in my Android project:

```
static void convert(unsigned int &c, const float &temp1, const float &temp2, const float &temp3) {
    if ( (temp3 * 6) < 1) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * 6 * temp3) * 100);

    else if ((temp3 * 2) < 1) c = (unsigned int) (temp1 * 100);

    else if ((temp3 * 3) < 2) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * (.66666 - temp3) * 6) * 100);

    else c = (unsigned int) (temp2 * 100);

    return;
}
```

During the code it gets called like this:

```
convert(r, temp1, temp2, temp3);
```

But when I compile it with the **ndk-build** command from the command line, then I get the following errors:

> Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported
>   version android-16.     [arm64-v8a] Compile        :
>   com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor
>   <=
>   com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c
>   jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:193:47:
>   error: 
>         expected ')' static void convert(unsigned int &c, const float &temp1, const float ...
>                                                 ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:193:33:
>   note: 
>         to match this '(' static void convert(unsigned int &c, const float &temp1, const float ...
>                                   ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:193:47:
>   error: 
>         parameter name omitted static void convert(unsigned int &c, const float &temp1, const float ...
>                                                 ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:194:11:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp3'
>       if ( (temp3 * 6) < 1) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * 6 * temp3...
>             ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:194:27:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'c'
>       if ( (temp3 * 6) < 1) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * 6 * temp3...
>                             ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:194:57:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp1'
>       if ( (temp3 * 6) < 1) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * 6 * temp3...
>                                                           ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:194:65:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp2'
>       if ( (temp3 * 6) < 1) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * 6 * temp3) * ...
>                                                                   ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:194:48:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp2'
>       if ( (temp3 * 6) < 1) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * 6 * temp3...
>                                                  ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:194:78:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp3'   ...(temp3 * 6) < 1) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * 6 * temp3) * 100);
>                                                                            ^
>   jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:196:15:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp3'
>       else if ((temp3 * 2) < 1) c = (unsigned int) (temp1 * 100);
>                 ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:196:31:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'c'
>       else if ((temp3 * 2) < 1) c = (unsigned int) (temp1 * 100);
>                                 ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:196:51:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp1'
>       else if ((temp3 * 2) < 1) c = (unsigned int) (temp1 * 100);
>                                                     ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:198:15:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp3'
>       else if ((temp3 * 3) < 2) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * (.666...
>                 ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:198:31:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'c'
>       else if ((temp3 * 3) < 2) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * (.666...
>                                 ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:198:61:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp1'
>       else if ((temp3 * 3) < 2) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * (.666...
>                                                               ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:198:69:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp2'   ...if ((temp3 * 3) < 2) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * (.66666 - temp...
>                                                                   ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:198:52:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp2'
>       else if ((temp3 * 3) < 2) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * (.666...
>                                                      ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:198:88:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp3'   ...< 2) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * (.66666 - temp3) * 6) * 100);
>                                                                      ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:200:10:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'c'
>       else c = (unsigned int) (temp2 * 100);
>            ^ jni/com_celik_abdullah_imageprocessingpart_processors_NativeImageProcessor.c:200:30:
>   error: 
>         use of undeclared identifier 'temp2'
>       else c = (unsigned int) (temp2 * 100);

I got that code from a .cpp file. When I delete the address operator (&) in the signature, then everything is fine (no errors) but I do not know if then the algorithm would work.

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compile C++ code with a C compiler, which will not work.

The obvious solution would be to compile it with a C++ compiler instead (e.g. by giving the source file a `.cpp` extension).

If for some reason you must use a C compiler, then you'll have to rewrite the function in C.
For starters, you can pass all those `const float` parameters by value instead of by reference (by getting rid of the `&`). I don't know why they were references in the first place.
That first parameter (`c`) is used as an output-parameter to which the result is written. So you'll have to change it from a reference to a pointer (i.e. `unsigned int *c`). Or better yet, skip the output parameter and have the function return its result instead:

```
static int convert(const float temp1, const float temp2, const float temp3) {
    unsigned int c;

    if ( (temp3 * 6) < 1) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * 6 * temp3) * 100);
    else if ((temp3 * 2) < 1) c = (unsigned int) (temp1 * 100);
    else if ((temp3 * 3) < 2) c = (unsigned int) ((temp2 + (temp1 - temp2) * (.66666 - temp3) * 6) * 100);
    else c = (unsigned int) (temp2 * 100);

    return c;
}
```

Calling code:

```
r = convert(temp1, temp2, temp3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `unsigned int &c` is a reference parameter and `&` is not "the address operator" in that case. However, references don't exist in C, which is why you get errors when compiling this C++ code in a .c file instead of .cpp